# Creating new array with corresponding values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have two arrays, one with react-icon components -

```js
const amenities = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Wifi",
    icon: <FaWifi />
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Kitchen",
    icon: <FaUtensils />
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Shower",
    icon: <FaShower />
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Bath",
    icon: <FaBath />
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Disabled Access",
    icon: <FaWheelchair />
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Lift",
    icon: <GrElevator />
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Air Con",
    icon: <TiWeatherSnow />
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Downtown",
    icon: <FaCity />
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "Coffee Maker",
    icon: <FaCoffee />
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Public Transport",
    icon: <FaSubway />
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    name: "Landmarks",
    icon: <FaToriiGate />
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: "Nice Scenery",
    icon: <FaImage />
  },
]
```

and one without that has come from a backend without the icon property

```js
chosenAmenities: [
    { name: 'Wifi', id: 1 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Shower' },
    { name: 'Air Con', id: 7 }
  ]
```

I was wondering how I could create a new array adding the correct react-icon component properties depending on the values that exist in the chosenAmenities array?

I have been able to add in a "test" value successfully like so...

```js
const updatedAmenitites = amenities.map(obj => ({...obj, test: "test"}));
```

However I am struggling to figure out how I would end up with this as a final product to display on the frontend:

```js
updatedAmenities: [
        { name: 'Wifi', id: 1, icon: <FaWifi /> },
        { id: 3, name: 'Shower', icon: <FaShower /> },
        { name: 'Air Con', id: 7, icon: <TiWeatherSnow /> }
      ]
```

I am using Next.js with React and fetching from firebase as a backend for context.

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have any mapping between name and icon component?

Comment: When you map your objects, you can use an if-statement, and if the `name` is a particular value, add your corresponding `icon`. Or instead, you could create a look-up object, eg: `{"Wifi": <FaWifi />, "Shower": <FaShower />, ...}`, if you do this, you can use the `.name` property to get the corresponding icon. You might find that you don't even need to add the `icon` property if you have this lookup already

Comment: I don't see any difference between input, output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just map with the `id` property that you have in the `chosenAmenities`.

```jsx
const amenities = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Wifi",
    icon: <FaWifi />,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Kitchen",
    icon: <FaUtensils />,
  },
];

const chosenAmenities = [
  { name: "Wifi", id: 1 },
  { id: 3, name: "Shower" },
  { name: "Air Con", id: 7 },
];

const updatedAmenities = chosenAmenities.map((e) => {
 const amenity = amenities.find((i) => i.id === e.id);
 if(!amenity) return e;
 return ({
  ...e,
  icon: amenity.icon,
 });
});
```

**References**

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_es6_spread.asp

Comment: that is close, but it is giving me the full object from amenities nested within the icon property - rather than just taking the isolated icon property and putting that into the correct object of updatedAmenitites

Comment: here is an image https://imgur.com/LobjuiV

Comment: This works - thank you so much for your help you are a beautiful person :)

Comment: Thank you, please upvote and [accept it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)

Comment: dont have enough reputation yet sorry :(

Comment: No worries. Happy Coding

Answer (score -1):

You can use `new Set` to create a hashMap and then `.filter` through amenities. Using the above will allow you to stay in O(n) instead of going quadratic.

```js
const amenities = [{ id: 1,name: "Wifi",icon: '<FaWifi />'},{id: 2,name: "Kitchen",icon: '<FaUtensils />'},{id: 3,name: "Shower",icon: '<FaShower />' },{id: 4,name: "Bath",icon: '<FaBath />'},{id: 5,name: "Disabled Access",icon: '<FaWheelchair />'},{id: 6,name: "Lift", icon: '<GrElevator />'},{
id: 7,name: "Air Con",icon: '<TiWeatherSnow />'},{id: 8,name: "Downtown", icon: ' <FaCity />'},{id: 9,name: "Coffee Maker",icon: '<FaCoffee />'},{id:10, name: "Public Transport", icon: '<FaSubway />'},{id: 11,name: "Landmarks",icon: '<FaToriiGate />'},{id: 12,name: "Nice Scenery",icon: '<FaImage />' },]


const chosenAmenities = [
    { name: 'Wifi', id: 1 },
    { name: 'Shower', id: 3, },
    { name: 'Air Con', id: 7 }
 ];
  
const hashMap = new Set((chosenAmenities).map(({ id }) => id));
const result = amenities.filter(({id}) => hashMap.has(id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Array.find() and search related object by Id

```
const updatedAmenitites = chosenAmenities.map(ca=> amenities.find(a=>a.id===ca.id))
```

Answer (score -1):

Following your route, this is another solution

```js
const updatedAmenitites = chosenAmenities.map(obj => {
  ...obj,
  icon: amenities[amenities.findIndex(a => a.id === obj.id)].icon
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).